# BookingConfirmation() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'amount'

Tags: python, django

I pretty new in Python and Django,and I am trying to build a hostel reservation using stripe.
I am trying to pass data(The price of the room) from my room detail view to the Charge view but I get the following error.

```html
TypeError at /booking/confirm/
BookingConfirmation() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'amount'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/booking/confirm/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
BookingConfirmation() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'amount'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hostel\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 113
Python Executable: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hostel\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

Here is my Room Detail View

```html
def RoomBookingView(request,pk):
    publishkey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if pk:
             room_id = Room.objects.get(pk = pk)
             amount = room_id.price
             student_id = request.user
             room_id.is_reserved = True,
           
             reservation = Reservation(
             room_id = room_id.id,
             student_id = student_id.id,
             
             
             )
             reservation.save()
             try:
                    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
                    room.is_reserved = True
                    amount = room_id.price
                    room.save()
             except BaseException:
                    pass
             
             return redirect(reverse('confirm', args=[amount]))
    context = {
        'STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY' : publishkey,   
    }
    return render(request,'room-detail.html',context)
```

And my Charge View

```html
def BookingConfirmation(request,*args,amount):
     amount = args
     if request.method == 'POST':
         charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            
            currency='usd', 
            amount = amount,
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
     return render(request,'booking-confirm.html',{})
```

Comment: Why are you calling a view from a view?

Comment: I ama newbie  Python and Django, But basically, what I wanted to do is to pass the amount variable from The RoomBookingView view to BookingConfirmation View to use it dynamically in the Stripe Charge

Comment: I think you can remove the parameter `amount` from your definition of `BookingConfirmation`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get the same error even after getting rid of the amount in my RoomBookingView

Comment: change `def BookingConfirmation(request,*args,amount):` to `def BookingConfirmation(request,*args):`